# Extract number of text file using bash

Tags: string, bash, shell, substring

I have a variable with the following string as input:

```
x}#guser{padding-bottom:7px !important;text-align:right}.gbh,.gbd{border-top:1px solid #c9d7f1;font-size:1px}.gbh{height:0;position:absolute;top:24px;width:100%}@media all{.gb1{height:22px;margin-right:>12,34 M<.5em;vertical-align:top}#gbar{float:left}}a.gb1,a.gb4{text-decoration:underline !important}a.gb1,a.gb4{color:#00c !important}.gbi .gb4{color:#dd8e27 !important}.gbf .gb4{color:#900 !important} </style><style>body,td,a,p,.h{font-family:arial,sans-serif}body{margin:0;overflow-y:scroll}#gog{padding:3px 8px 0}td{line-height:.8em}.gac_m td{line-height:17px}form{margin-bottom:20px}.h{color:#36c}.q{color:#00c}.ts td{padding:0}.ts{border-collapse:collapse}em{font-weight:bold;font-style:normal}.lst{height:25px;width:496px}.gsfi,.lst{font:18px arial,sans-serif}.gsfs{font:17px arial,sans-serif}.ds{display:inline-box;display:inline-block;margin:3px 0 4px;margin-left:4px}input{font-family:inherit}a.gb1,a.gb2,a.gb3,a.gb4{color:#11c !important}body{background:#fff;color:black}a{color:#11c;text-decoration:none}a:hover,a:active{text-decoration:underline}.fl a{color:#36c}a:visited{color:#551a8b}a.gb1,a.gb4{text-decoration:underline}a.gb3:hover{text-decoration:none}#ghead a.gb2:hover{color:#fff !important}.sblc{padding-top:5px}.sblc a{display:block;margin:2px 0;margin-left:13px;font-size:11px}.lsbb{background:#eee;border:solid 1px;border-color:#ccc #999 #999 #ccc;height:30px}.lsbb{display:block}.ftl,#fll a{display:inline-block;margin:0 12px}.lsb{background:url(/images/nav_logo229.png) 0 -261px repeat-x;border:none;color:#000;cursor:pointer;height:30px;margin:0;outline:0;
```

Somewhere in the string we can found:

```
>12,34 M<
```

Is it possible to extract the number 12,34 and put it into a variable?

I have several of these strings, but the pattern >number M< is always the same.

Thank you for suggestions :)

Answer (score 1):

you can try reading you input variable to use grep Regex

```
echo $variable | grep -Eo "[0-9,]{1,} M"
```

See comments: Use `<<<` avoiding the `echo` and assign to a variable:

```
finalVar=$(grep -Eo '[0-9,]{1,} M' <<< "$variable")
```

Comment: Nice solution. I don't know why people avoid here-strings. So with here-strings you can go with `grep -Eo '[0-9,]{1,} M' <<< "$variable"` but that's probably matter of personal preference. Other thing I would say is that your answer is not complete, since it's not assigned to a variable. Don't assume that the guy who asked always knows to do it.

Comment: You're right, I do use here-string but it didn't came in mind, so the right answer should be
 finalVar=$(grep -Eo '[0-9,]{1,} M' <<< "$variable")

Comment: For a better fix (matrch `<>` and at most 1 `[,]`), use `finalVar=$(grep -Eo '>[0-9]{1,}[,]{0,1}[0-9]{0,} M<' | tr -d '<>' <<< "${variable}"`

Answer (score 0):

When you have the pattern in each line, use

```
resultvar=$(sed -r 's/.*>([0-9]+[,]{0,1}[0-9]+ M)<.*/\1/' <<< "$variable")
```

When you more more than 1 line in your input and only one match, use

```
resultvar=$(sed -nr 's/.*>([0-9]+[,]{0,1}[0-9]+ M)<.*/\1/p' <<< "$variable")
```

When you can have more than one match, please specify the desired result (only the first or last match, an array, a set of variables or an error message).

Comment: Why use `{1,}` instead of `+` etc. ?

Comment: @PesaThe You are right, I changed `{1,}`  into `+`. I am not sure which of the next numbers are valid, so I gave a simple solution: `1`; `1,`;`,2`.